# MIPI? MIPI-CSI2? are they same?

Tags: camera

I'm reading cmos camera specifications. But I can not understand one thing. Is the MIPI means MIPI-CSI 2, or is it a different interface? This is the link of the camera I have been interested in.

http://www.ovt.com/download_document.php?type=sensor&sensorid=173

Answer (score 2):

[MIPI](http://mipi.org/) is not an interface. It's a group that defines the interface. 
MIPI-CSI2 is the camera interface defined by the MIPI group. MIPI-DSI would be the interface to connect a display device.

The MIPI group keeps all specifications closed :-( .